# How to match any url contains a certain string (such as .jsp) in Django?

Tags: python, django, regex, security, url-mapping

I'd like to soft reject any path that contains a string, such as `.jsp` in the Django 3.  Here is my url.py:

```py
from django.urls import re_path
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

re_path(
    r"^.*\.jsp\??.*$",
    TemplateView.as_view(template_name="404.txt", content_type="text/plain"),
),
```

The above path pattern can match an ordinary string like `/whatever.jsp`, but cannot match the following probing string.  How to improve my re_path pattern to match this? Thanks!

```
/content/..%3B/crx/packmgr/list.jsp%3B%0A%3B%0A%3B%0A%3B%0A%3B%0A%3B%0A%3B%0A%3B%0A%3B%0A%3B%0A%3B%0A%3B%0A%3B%0A%3B%0A%3B%0A%3B%0Aa.css?_dc=1615863080856&_charset_=utf-8&includeVersions=true
```

Comment: Your pattern matches both strings right? See https://regex101.com/r/uuwFNX/1

Comment: It does when testing under the regex checker, however, not matched when Django run for unknown reason.  The regex provided by Kiran is better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about this regex `r"[^\.](.*)\.jsp(.*)"`